# Django Deployment with Gunicorn

Tags: django, render, gunicorn

Sep 9 05:57:41 PM  [2023-09-09 22:57:41 +0000] [52] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
Sep 9 05:57:41 PM  [2023-09-09 22:57:41 +0000] [52] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:10000 (52)
Sep 9 05:57:42 PM  [2023-09-09 22:57:42 +0000] [52] [INFO] Using worker: sync
Sep 9 05:57:42 PM  [2023-09-09 22:57:42 +0000] [53] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 53
Sep 9 05:57:42 PM  [2023-09-09 22:57:42 +0000] [54] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 54
Sep 9 05:57:42 PM  [2023-09-09 22:57:42 +0000] [55] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 55
Sep 9 05:57:42 PM  [2023-09-09 22:57:42 +0000] [56] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 56
Sep 9 06:08:06 PM  [2023-09-09 23:08:06 +0000] [52] [INFO] Handling signal: term
Sep 9 06:08:06 PM  [2023-09-09 23:08:06 +0000] [53] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 53)
Sep 9 06:08:06 PM  [2023-09-09 23:08:06 +0000] [54] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 54)
Sep 9 06:08:06 PM  [2023-09-09 23:08:06 +0000] [55] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 55)
Sep 9 06:08:06 PM  [2023-09-09 23:08:06 +0000] [56] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 56)
Sep 9 06:08:12 PM  [2023-09-09 23:08:12 +0000] [52] [INFO] Shutting down: Master

Worker keeps exitting without logs. gunicorn wsgi:application is my build command. The app is in the root of the directory, where gunicorn launches from

Attempted debugging by adding flags to gunicorn, no logs showed

Comment: "Handling signal: term". Checking [termination signals](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Termination-Signals.html): something is telling your server to shut down. Check how you start the server and whatever else may shut it down.